# Youtrack error when import project from Jira

Tags: import, jira, youtrack

Error message:

> Script failed with error: YouTrack was unable to assign a unique name
> to one of the entities from the impo rt source (ссылка 'blocks'),
> which has caused the import to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. open https://youtrack.youdomain.com/admin/issueLinkTypes
2. Rename three records:

- Depend_1    blocks  is blocked by
- Cloners clones  is cloned by
- Problem-incident    causes  is caused by

Comment: You can also just safely remove all the links that start end with _n (where n — any number, e.g., Depend_0). After that restart the import and it should go through.